# Paytm not returning to App after successful transaction

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway, paytm

I am integrating Paytm Payment Gateway in my Android App. I am able to do transactions successful, but after a successful the function "onTransactionResponse" is not executing and the app is stuck on the successful transaction screen. After i click the back button and cancelling the transaction, then the execution is going to "onBackPressedCancelTransaction". I am following paytm Integration docs. Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: Did you found any solution?